# Setting up Authentication flow using Client Credentials

Tags: identity-server

I am trying to establish Client_credentials authentication flow from my .NET API to fetch the items, sort of like
https://doc.sitecore.com/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/use-bearer-tokens-in-client-applications.html, without Sitecore Context/ libraries in my API.

I have done the configuration changes in the below files

```
\Config\production\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml

\sitecore\Sitecore.Plugin.IdentityServer\Config\identityserver.xml
```

It should ideally fetch the token from https://identityserver/connect/token

The Postman doesn't generate the token from the above site core URL in spite of passing the below values, It has been a struggle, Anyone who is aware of what I am missing, please?

```
    <CredentialsClient>
      <ClientId>test</ClientId>
      <ClientName>test</ClientName>
      <AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
      <IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
      <AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser>true</AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser>
      <RequireClientSecret>false</RequireClientSecret>
      <AllowedGrantTypes>
        <AllowedGrantType1>client_credentials</AllowedGrantType1>
      </AllowedGrantTypes>
      <AllowedCorsOrigins>
      </AllowedCorsOrigins>
      <AllowedScopes>
         <AllowedScope1>openid</AllowedScope1>
        <AllowedScope2>sitecore.profile</AllowedScope2>
        <AllowedScope3>sitecore.profile.api</AllowedScope3>
      </AllowedScopes>
      <ClientSecrets>
```

Does it work only from Code and not from postman or is some configuration missing at site core end?

2nd query is that whether this can be achieved with the Azure Identity provider, If yes kindly share links of external identity provider too.

Friends, Please help. The above code flow

Comment: You may want to focus your question into a single question and ask your other queries as separate questions.

Comment: question is a little confusing but for the second part, https://sitecore.derekc.net/setting-up-azure-active-directory-integration-with-sitecore-identity-server-sitecore-9-1/ check this might help maybe. Also, check below https://sam-solutions.us/azure-ad-b2c-tutorial-how-to-authenticate-in-sitecore-via-azure/

Comment: Do you mean to set up Federated Authentication using Client Azure AD?

Comment: No Gayathri, the purpose was to establish a Client credentials flow with Sitecore and was able to do it by referring to the MVCclient sample values in the Sitecore configuration. Thanks u all for helping me/ trying to.